# EPS figure in pdf output is transparent and placed over text - a Latex problem

Tags: latex, eps, figures

I have generated eps figures in MATLAB and am using them in Latex. (Miktex 2.9 with TexnicCenter).

I dont understand why the output ( PS-> pdf ) shows the figure on top of the text below it. Also the figure appears to have a  transparent background through which you can see the text over which it is placed.

the name of the figure file is TEER.eps

Here is what I have in my code:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{center}

\scalebox{0.4}{\includegraphics*[0.6in,10.4in][7.9in,4.7in]{imgs/TEER}}

\caption{TEER plot}
\label{fig:TEERplot}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
.
.
.
.
```

Kindly let me know what Im doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: The [TeX/LaTeX SE site](http://tex.stackexchange.com) might be a better place to ask this question (seeing as that's where the LaTeX experts hang out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `graphicx` (which is recommended), you should use the form `\includegraphics[width=...]{imgs/TEER}`.  You give the actually intended width to that; the image is automatically scaled.  You could also give the height instead.  In your case, it seems like you want something like

```
\includegraphics[width=2.92in]{imgs/TEER}
```

You can also use relative widths to the textwidth:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{imgs/TEER}
```

or

```
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{imgs/TEER}
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked well. I used the following command to crop too:
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth, trim = 0in 7.4in 0in 0in, clip]{imgs/TEER}